# How should my smart dimmer be connected?

Tags: electrical

I have replaced normal outlets and wall switches before. I'm comfortable enough to know I have to turn off the breaker before doing it. I purchased my very own DH6HD-1BZ with the intentions of wiring it myself, however, there are only 2 wires that I can see in the wall and this looks to me like it could take up to 4. The blue wire out of the wall is one wire (although it looks like 2, I couldn't tell that until I disassembled it)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's hiding in the electrical tape? How old is the house?

Comment: your current switch appears to be a single-pole (one switch, one set of lights) or is at least wired that way but your new switch is a three way (two switches control one set of lights.)  I'm guessing you don't need a three-way switch here, is that right?

Comment: @JimmyJames his new switch is used both ways, check the instruction sheet.  Most smart switches are dual role—that is they don’t sell single pole and 3-ways that are separate, it’s “one size fits all”.

Comment: @Tyson Right but if he wants to do a 3-way, he's SOL without pulling wires from what I see.

Comment: @JimmyJames he just needs to replace his current single pole switch, using the correct single pole wiring diagram in the instructions.  Nowhere in the question is he adding additional switches, so need to pull wire.

Answer (score 2):

I found the instruction sheet [here](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/DI-000-DH6HD-02A-W.pdf).

From that:

We can’t tell which your hot feed is:  blue or yellow.  You need to determine that, one way is a meter, another way is a non-contact voltage detector with the old switch turned off.

On the new switch:
BLK is where the hot wire goes.  (My guess is the blues)

RD is where the load goes, that will be other wire on the old switch.(my guess is yellow)

WH is neutral.  You’ll need a 6” white wire scrap for this. Attach that scrap  here and add the other end to the wire-nutted bundle of neutrals in the back of the box

You won’t use YL/RD in this instance. Leave the label covering the screw per the instructions.  (It would only be used when multiple switches control the same light.)

The difference is your old switch didn’t need neutral.  Smart switches always do, and fortunately neutral is available in the box (that is not always the case.)

What is in that tape? It shouldn’t be there. Splices require wire nuts instead.

Comment: Note that not all smart switches require a neutral connection. One example is the Lutron Caseta dimmer smart switch. Lutron does have an on/off smart switch that does require a neutral that is made for switching certain loads such as ceiling fans or bathroom exhaust fans. You would also use the latter type for lighting loads that are non-dimmable such as lights with a magnetic ballast.